# Flowplayer on IE8 Loading issues

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, flowplayer

Hay guys im trying to use Flowplayer to load some videos on a flyout on ie 8. I think it is not a compatability issue since I have a page where videos load perfectly and the player is displayed. This only occures when I try to load the video using java script onto a flyout. All I get as of now is a bliack space where the player should be.

```
    <!-- Internet Explorer Flyout -->
    <div id="videoFlyoutIE<?=$itemz['newsID']?>" class="popUpWrapper" style="display:none;position:absolute;top:10px;left:auto;">
            <div class="firstPopupDiv" style="left:center;height:auto;width:620px;">
                <div class="popupDivInner" style="display:block;" class="hideSteps">
                    <h1 style="color:#333333;" ><?=$itemz['title']?><div id="title"></div></h1>
                    <hr/>
                    <div id="tst<?=$itemz['newsID']?>">
                        <center>
                            <a id="player<?=$itemz['newsID']?>" style=";display:block; height:365px; width:auto;"></a>  
                        </center>
                        <br/>   
                        <hr/>
                        <?php echo $itemz['description'];?>
                    </div>  
                    <a class="btnRed clickable floatRight" style="position:relative;top:12px;" onclick="closeVideo('<?=$itemz['newsID']?>');"><?=$lang[109]?></a>   
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Here are my loading functions

```
    function showVideo(ID,link)
    {
    if(navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
    {
        showPopup("videoFlyoutIE"+ID);
        startVideo(ID,link);

        }
        else
        {
            showPopup("videoFlyout"+ID)
        }
 }   


function startVideo(ID,link)
 {
    $("#tst"+ID).fadeIn("slow", function()
    {
        $f("player"+ID, {src: "players/nobranding.swf", wmode: 'opaque'},
        {
            clip: 
            {
                autoPlay: true
            },

            playlist: 
            [
                'videos/IMPORTS/'+link,
            ],
            plugins:
            {
                controls: 
                {
                    playlist: true
                }
            }
        }
        ).ipad();
    });
}






function showPopup(popupID, scrollToTop, slideDown) {

    if (scrollToTop === undefined){
        scrollToTop = true;
    }
    else{
        scrollToTop = false;
    }

    if (slideDown === undefined){
        slideDown = false;
    }
    else{
        slideDown = true;
    }

    // see if there is an overlay, and if not, insert it to the begining of the body
    if($(".overlay").length != 1) {
        $(".overlay").remove();

        $("body").prepend("<div class='overlay'></div>");
    }

    // Ensure overlay covers the entire window, not just the viewport
    $(".overlay").css({'height': $(document).height()});
    //$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: error_location}, 'slow', 'swing', function(){firstError.focus();});
    // fade in transparent layer (can't use fadeIn because that screws with opacity)
    $(".overlay").show().animate(
        {
            opacity: 0.7
        },
        "slow"
    );

    if (scrollToTop){
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 'slow', 'swing');
    }

    // Show the popup
    if (!slideDown){
        $("#" + popupID).fadeIn("slow");
    }
    else{
        $("#" + popupID).slideDown();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no problem with your code to be run on my IE8/WinXP machine after some modification. I suspect one of your javascript has some issues. Can you elaborate what is your showPopup() method? It would be better if you can provide a whole page or a test link.

Comment: I have posted the function as you requested.